# Retrieving data speed tweaks SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, performance, query-performance

I have a database in Microsoft SQL Server 2005.

I have table with 3 columns, namely `HASHKEY (BIGINT)`, `NOTE_ID (INT)` and `TIME_OFFSET (INT)`.

Columns `HASHKEY` has 19 digit `BIGINT` values, which can DUPLICATE. But values will be always of 19 digits.

I have application mainly depends on data in this table. Application retrieves data from this table with query like:

```
select HASHKEY, NOTE_ID, TIME_OFFSET 
from TABLE_NAME 
where HASHKEY in (<list of around 30000 hashkeys>)
```

But this query takes around 2 minutes to retrieve data. This is my problem. The application is real time processing application, and need to retrieve data in about 5 seconds. How can I tweak things in server, so time to retrieve data can be decreased?

I have indexed the table by HASHKEY column when I created table, but still retrieving data is taking much time.

Is there any setting which I can do in database to so time can be decreased? I will welcome any type of solution. But I need to solve this. I am not very expert in this.

Also HASHKEY is just random values of 19 digits, no relation with other values.

Result of following query is,

```
select count(HASHKEY) from TABLE_NAME
go
select count(distinct(HASHKEY)) from TABLE_NAME
```

Result:

```
225899932
189200251
```

Time taken: 2 minutes, 1 second

**EDIT**

This is script to create table:

```
USE [fp]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[fp_core]    Script Date: 09/13/2013 22:40:43 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[fp_core](
    [hashkey] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [note_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [timeoffset] [int] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I will ask random set of around 30000 hashkeys for data, no any ordering.

When I was having around 20000000 rows in table, query was taking less than 2 seconds, but now retrieval time is increasing.

**EDIT**

And here is script to create index, only one index in this table.

```
USE [fp]
GO
/****** Object:  Index [IX_fp_core]    Script Date: 09/13/2013 23:04:24 ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_fp_core] ON [dbo].[fp_core] 
(
    [hashkey] ASC
)WITH (SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Please help me.

Comment: Could you please edit the question to include the entire scripted table definition, including all indexes? We need to know exactly what you mean about indexing the table by `HASHKEY`. Also, when the application runs one of those queries, are the `HASHKEY` values sequential, or random? Posting an execution plan would also help. I get the feeling that even if there is an index on `HASHKEY`, too many rows are being asked for and the plan is table scanning all the time. Which edition of SQL Server (Standard, Enterprise, etc.) are you using?

Comment: Yeah.  I'd need to know about your table definition and indexes, too.  Is your clustered index on the non-unique HASHKEY?  Is HASHKEY sequential?  Also, if your query really does give a list of 30,000 hashkeys with a "hashkey in," well, that's not going to provide you with optimal performance.

Comment: what can be problem? Please help me? What are the ways to boost query performance when situations is like: so many records, around 500 million and want to retrieve only 30000 records. Records can have duplicate values, say out of all records, only 60% are distinct.

Comment: I am not DB expert, I am Java developer and created DB myself, now problem arose, I have not did advanced things in DB, just created table, and indexed non-unique column HASHKEY. HASHKEY values are random.

Comment: @Meraman How are you passing the haskeys on the `IN`? (I mean, are they retrieved from another `SELECT`?, are you writing them?). Also, if `HASHKEY` is always a 19 digit number, you might wanna think on using a `CHAR(19)` instead

Comment: What's the query plan?  To retrieve 30 K out of 200 M records in a field with very high cardinality, I'd expect it to seek against the `HASHKEY` index, but it sounds like it might be scanning, or maybe not using it at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your table is a "heap," which means that it doesn't have a clustered index.  The short version of what that means is that your data isn't laid out on the disk in a logical way.  A heap really isn't an optimal structure for an actively updated table.  [Here's an excellent video on heaps.](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2012/05/video-heaps/)

So, my suggestions--please test them before deploying them in production--are:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

USE fp; ALTER TABLE fp_core ADD ID bigint NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1)
GO

USE fp; CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_fp ON fp_core (ID) WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

COMMIT
```

This will take some time to complete AND will be a blocking query, so do it during downtime.

This will give you a clustered index and lay out your table on a completely random sequential number, unfortunately, but since you don't have any non-unique values that might be the best course of action.

I would then include the columns note_id and timeoffset in your nonclustered index on HASHKEY.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

USE [fp]
GO

IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.indexes WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[fp_core]') AND name = N'IX_Agency_TIMESTAMP')
DROP INDEX [IX_fp_core] ON [dbo].[fp_core] WITH ( ONLINE = OFF )
GO

USE [fp]
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_fp_core] ON [dbo].[fp_core] 
(
    [hashkey] ASC
)
INCLUDE ( [note_id],[timeoffset])
WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

COMMIT
```

(Or you could do it through the GUI.  If you right-click on the index and choose properties, there's an included columns pane.)

This will hopefully have the effect of replacing your heap scans with nonclustered index seeks, but since your query has a "where in [30,000 items], it might do a index scan instead.  Either way, it won't be rooting around in the heap, which I expect will be a good thing.

Comment: I will be retrieving data based on HASHKEY values, not based on ID values. Like select * from TABLE_NAME where HASHKEY in (....), not like select * from TABLE_NAME where ID in (....)

Comment: Yes, I understand that.  On the other hand, since HASHKEY is not unique, it's a poor choice for a clustered index.  Also, select * is... not optimal.